# Modify html content to display based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to reuse [this code](https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multi-step-requirement-form-progress-and-validation-52577416) adapted to my website, the fact is that depending on what the user selects I need the next step to be one or the other. In the provided example, the user can select: 'Create Website', 'Website Relaunch' and 'Don't Know' so I want the content of the next step to be different, depending on the user's choice.

In other words, if I select 'Create Website' I want to get A, B and C inputs/fields in the next step (name, email, phone, whatever...). But if I select Website Relaunch or Don't Know, I want to get X, Y, Z inputs/fields.

I am little bit lost with jQuery. Could anybody help me please?

[DEMO CODE HERE](https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multi-step-requirement-form-progress-and-validation-52577416)

Comment: Record choice
This click event triggers a function that changes the inputs/fields then show it

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought, but how can I do that? @onlycau Thank you!

Comment: Only used native js and vue to do similar functions,
know nothing about jquery
But if you have thoughts, this can't be a problem. /feel confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all possible fields in the HTML but hide them on init.
assuming you use the `.form-group` wrapper it could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-group').css('display', 'none');
})
```

Then you define 3 functions which you can add as onclick to the three options on the first slide. Something like `<div class="row justify-content-center d-flex" onclick="defineCreateFormFields()">`.

The functions must do something like this:

```
function defineCreateFormFields() {
    $('.form-group').css('display', 'none'); // make sure you reset all fields back to display: none initially
    $('#email').parent('.form-group').css('display', 'block');
    $('#xyz').parent('.form-group').css('display', 'block');
    ...
}
```

I see there are form validation functions aswell. Remember to adjust them to your needs aswell.

happy coding!

Comment: Thank you so much, I was looking for something like that!

Comment: Instead of using ```.form-group```, shouldn't I use ```card-body pt-0```?

Comment: @Gera i just saw that the code example is using the `.form-group` to wrap the label and the input element. Depending on your HTML code and classnames a different selector could make more sense.

Comment: Thank you! I guess the tricky point here...is how to combine the onclick event for the selected image + onclick event for the "next" button. I am stucking here...How can I display some html depending on the previous 2 onclick events? Nesting the onclick?

Like:

```$("#image1").click(function(){

         $("#nextbutton").click(function(){
     //show some specific content based on the previous clicks
          ...
          }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if i get it correctly. But you want to "remember" which image is selected when hitting the "next" button? You could set a variable `selectedOption` and set when an image is selcted. When then hitting the "next" button, you can read the value of that variable and so you know which option has been selected before the "next" button was hit.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually too broad and/or opnion-based. But think about in simple steps, what will happen:
Before you have clicked, all form fields have the state hidden. (pressumingly `display:none;`) The formfields are wrapped into `<div class="card-body pt-0">...</div>` container. There are serveral of it. After a mouseclick a javascript is running let one appear.

My suggestion is:

Copy the field blocks and fill them with your own fields. Make sure that they get the same look. Add a "unique" dummy css class to all containers there the fields wrapped in. The given name of those css classes should contains a fix and a dynamic part. Example:
`"showFormFields_1"`, `"showFormFields_2"`, and so on.

The linked javascript **could** be:

```
//At first: hide all divs
$("div .card-body .pt-0").hide(); 
//then make only div block visible with a particular css class 
$("div .card-body .pt-0 .showFormfields_" + selectionValue).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Too broad? I think it's quite specific. I'll try to do it as you said.